# Does the damage from Fire Traps stack?

Tags: path-of-exile

If I lay three fire traps in the same place, and a mob steps on them, does he take 3x the DoT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, multiple instances of the burning ground damage from Fire Trap **will NOT stack**.

Only *different sources* of burning damage can stack. For example, an Ignite debuff from a spell's critical hit and the Fire Trap ground burn will stack.

When 2 of the same burning sources are present the highest damage source will take effect. Multiple effects can still apply, like 2 Ignites on one mob, but only the highest damage one will actually deal damage.

Once the highest damage effect ends, if another instance of that effect was applied and still has duration left, it will then do what damage it has left. This goes for Righteous Fire, Ignite, and Fire Trap's ground burn effect. Searing Bond, a recently added skill, is an exception and the beams can stack with itself.

This is why you should try to spread out Fire traps a little bit whenever possible.

[Posted by](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/328132/page/2#p2863946) **Mark_GGG**, PoE developer and creator of the games skills and their mechanics.

> ...Ignite, RF, ground fire and now Searing Bond are all separate
>   sources of burning damage, and all stack. **Ignite, RF and ground fire
>   do not stack with themselves** (only the highest of each takes effect at
>   a time), but do with each other.
>
> Searing bond beams stack.

As of Patch 1.0.5 [Searing Bond Beams no longer stack.](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/748326)

Comment: +1 and accepted, for ciing GGG employee source.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer! :) Could you add a link to where he said that so I can read the thread?

Comment: Please don't edit quotes, I understand that the information is outdated, but in that case leave a comment saying so.

Comment: Added the information outside of the quote.

Answer (score 0):

The DoT of Firetrap is actually a fire-based health degeneration. So yes, health degeneration from all sources stacks.
If you can tank strong monsters, a typical use is to spam firetraps under you so the enemy takes all possible damage.

Comment: Could you please link a source?  I've never heard of this "fire-based health degeneration" you are talking about.

Comment: I cannot currently test this, but I believe the easiest way to test it would be to have more than one player with the fire trap skill gem, each of you lay a trap, then lure a single enemy into the traps, one of you tanks the enemy while the other watches the health bar. Try this again with 2 traps each and then with three traps each, if the single monster(preferably one of the same kind) dies faster with the increased amount of traps then you have your answer.